# Life Universe and Everything

Tags: java

[image]

I am new to CodeChef and I am getting the following output as error on CodeChef (An online platform for coding) editor and I am not able to submit my code.

I want to ask

> 1)Is My Approach towards the problem right and
>
> 2)When this error come?
>
> 3)Why I am getting compilation error?

MyApproach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Prog1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int a = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        int t = 1;
        while (t != 0) {
            a = sc.nextInt();
            if (a != 42) System.out.println(a);
            else t = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In my eclipse editor output shown is:

> 34
>   34
>   53
>   53
>   42

But I am getting following exception on Codechef editor:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>     at Prog1.main(Main.java:15)

Thankx in advance

Comment: If it works on your Eclipse, why bother? Contact CodeChef to see what is wrong with their editor if you want to. Your code is fine by the way. No reason to change it.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Yes,you are right But I can still make a mistake in understanding.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Do you know Why the post have negative votes.I explained everything what I did and wrote my own code

Comment: It is certainly because there is no problem to solve. Your code works fine. The problem is the CodeChef editor, not your code.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Okay,So,next time,I need to make sure I didn't put all right Ans even if I know  Ans.So,that the problem can be solved by others.Negative Votes certainly means very Bad.

Comment: negative votes mean not relevant. That's it. Not hatred

Comment: @Tom Where? Tested it, works.

Comment: @YassinHajaj *"Where?"* Right in my eyes -.- I missed `t = 0` in the `else` branch. So there is nothing wrong with the code itself, but its still quite strange that CodeChef itself has such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue is that your `Scanner` is attempting to read text when none exists. Try the Scanner's `hasNextInt()` method:

```
int a = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean t = false;
while (!t) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        a = sc.nextInt();
        if (a != 42)
            System.out.println(a);
        else
            t = true;
    }
}
```

Also, you should be using a `boolean` instead of an `int` (for `t`).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing brackets for the if statement.

```
    while(t!=0)

   {

     a=sc.nextInt();

     if (a != 42) {
         System.out.println(a);
     }
     else {
         t=0;
     }
   }
```

This will not print 42 when reached however, you would need to add the system print call again for when a does equal 42:

```
if (a != 42) {
         System.out.println(a);
     }
     else {
         System.out.println(a);
         t=0;
     }
```